# Fail to login to sudo user on VPS

Tags: ssh, vps, ssh-keys

- VPS Supplier: DigitalOcean
- OS: Cent OS 7
- Client: Mac OS X 10.10.3 bash

### Root

I login as `root` and created a sudo user `me`. Then I configured the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as following:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
UsePAM no
```

### Sudo User

I generated the private/public keys on local client with `ssh-keygen`. Then I login as `me` and created `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, pasted the content of `id_rsa.pub` (local client) into `.ssh/authorized_keys` (VPS).

### Question

I can login as `root` via ssh key and switch to `me` by `su -l me`. However, when I tried to login by `ssh me@remote_host`, the error `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).` is raised. I verified the content of `authorized_keys` and ensured it is correct.

Comment: Did you verify permissions on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: You seem to have missed the important warning stating that: `# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several problems.`

Comment: @EEAA I changed the permission to `400` (i.e. `r-- --- ---`).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I set `UsePAM yes` (default config) but still could not login to `me` via ssh.

Comment: In that case check the log `/var/log/secure` and find out _why_ the connection failed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I found the record: `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/me/.ssh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acknowledgement to @MichaelHampton and @EEAA. It turned out the problem is due to the permission of `authorized_keys` and `.ssh/`. They should be 600 and 700 respectively. (c.f. [here](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/))